# Woman Jesuit priest protagonist

Tags: story-identification, religion, first-contact

I am looking for the title of a sf novel that features a Jesuit who is a woman? It’s a first contact scenario, I think. I remember that the priest had shaved her head as a token of her total dedication. I read it at least 15 years ago, maybe more, as many as 30. It’s been driving me nuts trying to identify it.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail as to what exactly is science fictional or fantastical about this story?

Comment: "first contact scenario" jumps out at me.

Comment: Are you certain the Jesuit was a female?  [The Sparrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sparrow_(novel)) sounds like it might fit the bill, and there is a main female character, but the Jesuit character is male.

Comment: http://www.adherents.com/lit/sf_jesuit.html

Comment: @jedicurt - That was my thought as well, but Emilio (The Jesuit) is def male.

Answer (score 4):

Julian May wrote two series with a female character who is a Jesuit priest. The Galactic Mileu series has a character who is a Jesuit priest. I can't remember if she shaves her head or not.

The Saga of Pliocene Exile also has a female character who I believe is a Jesuit priest. Sometimes she is referred to as a nun, but the terms priest and nun are used interchangeably I think.

Both are scifi and was published in the 1980's.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely the Galactic Mileu series by Julian May.  The original 4 book Pliocene Saga.
She then wrote 2 sets of prequels, and they are great in their own right.

I have not read the First Contact series, but if i remember, one of the prequels had one of the daughters of denis remilard as a jesuit priest.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answer

Comment: it adds more information as I describe more characters as jesuits.   However, his daughter was not the biggest character in those 2 books.